# I made a mistake on my previous granted UK visa which I now realised when filling out a new application

Tags: visas, uk

I made a typing error filling out my one of my parent's date of birth, I switched up the digits from 46 to 64. Should I correct this now when filling out a new UK visitor visa application? I corrected it and left a note at the end clearing the whole thing saying I made a mistake last time and this time I've double checked everything. Will this result into a 10 year ban?

Comment: No. The ban is for deliberate deception, not a typing error in a relatively inconsequential field.

Answer (score 3):

While we cannot predict whether or not anyone will be issued a particular visa, it's extremely unlikely that anyone will take issue with such a minor mistake in an inconsequential field about your parents.

So go ahead and apply for the visa.